# jest/react-testing-library ant-design/chart worker error

Tags: jestjs, antd, react-testing-library

test case execution fails while using charts from @ant-design/charts, I even use jest-canvas-mock but the issue didn't resolve, here is [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHHu6.png) .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [also don't post images of your errors](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) instead provide a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the canvas package, because jest converts the canvas of the antd graph to div so after installing this package your test cases will work.

```
class Worker {
  constructor(stringUrl) {
    this.url = stringUrl;
    this.onmessage = () => {};
  }
  
  postMessage(msg) {
    this.onmessage(msg);
  }
}
global.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn();
window.Worker = Worker;
```

And then use this code above your describe

Hope this works for you.